# How can I add List of objects in a conditional state in guided decision table?

Tags: redhat, jbpm, redhat-bpm

I am working on a Guided decision table in JBPM.
I have a requirement like I have 1 college object in that I have a Student and a Fee object.
I want to apply a condition on multiple Student objects by passing a JSON containing College object and multiple Student objects in that. An then want to apply a discount on Fee object as it contains multiple fee variable in it. Like

```
College{
String name;
String city;
Student student;
Fee fee;
}

Student{
 String name;
 int id;
 float fatherincome;
}

Fee{
int tutionFee;
float examFee;
}
```

So here I want to apply condition in a decision table that according to each student's father income concession on fee will be given. So I will pass Json of college like it:

Basically, this is JSON so I want to know that how can I achieve this thing in guided decision table. When I am making a condition in GDT then able to select only student and fee as normal fields from college Data object but I want to select fields from Student and Fee objects for my requirement so How can I select this. Please help me. Any suggestions or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: share with us what you tried

Comment: HI @Bashir I tried to add college objects fields in condition. But when I am adding then I am getting Student as a normal field but not getting as object there.

Comment: HI @bashir I tried to add college objects fields in condition. But when I am adding then I am getting Student as a normal field but not getting as an object there. How Can I select an object from a class as an object rather than the normal field in GDT for condition and action?

Comment: bro share a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @bashir, I Understand your concern but it is UI based tool so HOW can I share code of snippet here. I can tell one thing that we have a school object in that we have Student Object and we need to apply logic on based of fields from Student object and we will send Json of Schoool object n that array of Student objects are there. So How can we use multiple Student objects fields in our Guided Decision Table for conditioning?

Comment: share a screenshot, will help to make it easier to understand and illustrate the issue